# In Coredata, how to get all IDs for specific table?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I want to fetch all IDs from a `coredata` table. For example, There is a Table called `Person`. There is a `personId` to uniquely identify  a record. I want to fetch all `personId` stayed in `Person` table. I don't know how I can do a query for that.

In SQLite Manager, I could have do it by executing the following query:

> **SELECT** ZPERSONID **FROM** ZPERSON;

But I have no idea how I can do it for iOS Coredata.

Comment: Do a fetch for the `Person` entity that has no predicate.  If you want to save memory, you can specify the results should in dictionary format and specify just the property you want.

Comment: What it will return ? Dictionary ?

Comment: Normally, an `NSFetchRequest` returns `NSManagedObject`s.  You can specify that you want a dictionary representation, and you can additionally specify the specific properties you want in the dictionary.  Check the class reference for `NSFetchRequest`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully this will help:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"personID"];
NSError *error;
NSArray *persons = [yourManagedContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: I used it but when I print array, it contains managed object having all the fields..

Comment: Thanks @Apoc, I have updated your answer adding some key properties for `NSFetchRequest`. It worked for me..